# How to create EMR cluster with custom Ubuntu Image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, amazon-ami

I am trying to launch an EMR cluster with custom AMI based on ubuntu OS.
In the process of creating an AMI, I have followed these steps:

1. launch an ec2 instance with ubuntu server 20.04 AMI available in the marketplace, with 1 root ebs volume
2. Install packages on that ec2 instance and create an AMI from that instance
   The problem is although the ec2 instance is launched with just 1 block device mapping, the AMI has 3 of them[custom AMI with 3 block device mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyC6E.png)
   While launching an EMR cluster with this custom AMI, this is the error I get[AMI must have only 1 ebs volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruFDa.png)

This is the ec2 instance with ubuntu os [ec2 instance with ubuntu os](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwGQQ.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure if this is allowed. You HAVE to use "Amazon Linux AMI" . Take that as base AMI, then install stuff on it and then use. You can't use any OS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-custom-ami.html